# Background countdown timer in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to run a countdown timer for 4-6 hrs. I have implemented the code but the code doesn't work in the background. Please help me with the solution.

Below is the code for the timer.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

   TextView medicineOneTimer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        medicineOneTimer = view.findViewById(R.id.medicineOneTimer);

        //INITIALIZE THE TIME
        long duration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1);

        initializeTimeCounter(duration);

        return view;
    }

    private void initializeTimeCounter(long duration) {
        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDur = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%d : %02d : %02d"
                        , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l)
                        , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)
                        , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));

                medicineOneTimer.setText(sDur);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // THIS IS THE EXAMPLE OF RECURRENCE RELATION OR RECURRENCE FUNCTION which means
                // Function is calling itself again and again and it will work infinity times or when the user dies
                initializeTimeCounter(duration);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Foreground Service`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).